# How to connect a Casio keyboard to a Lenovo i-320 with Ubuntu 18.04 using a USB cable?

Tags: sound, keyboard, music, midi

I have a Casio CTK 850 IN keyboard connected to my Ubuntu machine using a USB cable without a MIDI cable (I don't have one). I saw a YouTube video illustrating such a connection to a Windows system. So I tried on my Linux machine using Audacity, but I am not able to reproduce the sound of the keyboard on the system.

I am getting the below output on terminal when I run the `lsusb` command after connecting the keyboard:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 07cf:6803 Casio Computer Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Audacity does not support MIDI devices; use something like MusE or Qtractor.

Comment: Finally succeeded to connect on LMMS. Have to explore it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Audacity [does *not* directly support MIDI keyboards/devices](https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Midi), so for your device you will need to find another application.

As you have [already found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150803/how-to-connect-casio-keyboard-to-lenovo-i-320-with-ubuntu-18-04-using-usb-cable#comment1913613_1150803), one such application that should do the job with your keyboard is [LMMS](https://lmms.io/lsp/). It is available in the Ubuntu repositories, so you can install it using:

```
sudo apt install lmms
```

It is also available from the [LMMS GitHub site](https://github.com/LMMS/lmms) as [an Appimage](https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/releases/download/v1.2.2/lmms-1.2.2-linux-x86_64.AppImage).

Other choices that are also available in the Ubuntu repositories could be:

- [**MusE**](https://muse-sequencer.github.io/) (Linux **Mus**ic **E**ditor): a Qt based audio/midi sequencer with editing and recording capabilities, which can be installed using:

  ```
  sudo apt install muse
  ```
- [**Qtractor**](https://qtractor.org/): An Audio/MIDI multi-track sequencer, which can be installed using:

  ```
  sudo apt install qtractor
  ```

<sub>Answer expanded from the comments by [CL.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150803/how-to-connect-casio-keyboard-to-lenovo-i-320-with-ubuntu-18-04-using-usb-cable#comment1913080_1150803) and [suhas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150803/how-to-connect-casio-keyboard-to-lenovo-i-320-with-ubuntu-18-04-using-usb-cable#comment1913613_1150803).</sub>